# Is there an operator in Airflow to create a table from a query in BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm looking for something like

```py
CreateBQTableOperator(
    query='select * from my_table',
    output_table='my_other_table'
)
```

I'm looking for either an already existing operator or code for such an operator. The operator should take another argument to decide if deleting the table (if the table exists) before recreating it or appending the query to the current table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Airflow >= 1.10 with providers you can use `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` This operator is using [`JobConfigurationQuery`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery) you can configure any option supported by the API using `configuration` parameter:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

execute_query_save = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="execute_query_save",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "select * from my_table",
            "useLegacySql": False,
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_EMPTY",
            'destinationTable': {
                'projectId': "my-project",
                'datasetId': "my_data_set",
                'tableId': "table2"
            },
        }
    },
)
```

---

For older Airflow versions you can use `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator`:

The operator has `destination_dataset_table`:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator

execute_query_save = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
    task_id="execute_query_save",
    sql="SELECT * FROM my_data_set.table1",
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    destination_dataset_table="my_data_set.table2",
    location="southamerica-east1",
    write_disposition="WRITE_EMPTY",
    create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
)
```

You can control over the requested behavior with setting the values for the parameters (reference for values from [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job)).

`write_disposition` options are:

WRITE_TRUNCATE: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data and uses the schema from the query result.

WRITE_APPEND: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.

WRITE_EMPTY: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.

`create_disposition` options are:

CREATE_IF_NEEDED: If the table does not exist, BigQuery creates the table.

CREATE_NEVER: The table must already exist. If it does not, a 'notFound' error is returned in the job result.

Comment: The [BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator) is deprecated, and the suggested replacement does not have a destination argument, is my only option now to write a INSERT INTO SELECT statement?""